# Binding multiple times to the same port?

Tags: java, windows, sockets, networking, windows-networking

Why doesn't the following code throw a "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind" 
exception?

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        try (ServerSocket socket1 = new ServerSocket();
             ServerSocket socket2 = new ServerSocket();
             ServerSocket socket3 = new ServerSocket())
        {
            int port = 10000;

            socket1.setReuseAddress(false);
            socket1.bind(new InetSocketAddress("0.0.0.0", port));

            socket2.setReuseAddress(false);
            socket2.bind(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", port));

            socket3.setReuseAddress(false);
            socket3.bind(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.2", port));

            Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        }
    }
}
```

Running 'netstat' afterwards displays:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>netstat -a -n | findstr 10000
  TCP    0.0.0.0:10000          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:10000        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.2:10000        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:10000             [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

I am running this on Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bit), and 'ipconfig /all' displays only one network adapter/interface (other network adapters are disabled). But, on some other machines, this program actually does throw the expected "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind"!

What could be going on?

Comment: They are not the same port. They are the same port number. Different sockets could get notified depending on which (virtual) interface the same packets are sent to.

Comment: But I have only one network interface on that machine

Comment: The loopback virtual interface has lots of IP addresses. You can listen to each of them separately, even with the same port number.

Comment: @JanDvorak Your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bind on the same port number on different IP addresses. The operating system can distinguish the incoming packets by their target IP address as well as their TCP port number.

The operating system has no problem keeping a separate serverSocket for `127.0.0.1:1000` and `127.0.0.2:1000`. It knows where each packet belongs - even if it opens a new connection.

Note that the IP address `0.0.0.0` is just that - an IP address (it is not a *valid* IP address in the sense IP packets could be sent there, but I can't any support for `0.0.0.0 == any` either). If you want to listen on all addresses, supply `null` to the InetSocketAddress instead. At this point, you have a greater chance of getting the desired exception (unless the OS decides that wildcard listens have lower priority and don't really overlap specific listens, so they can bind both).

Also note that setting `setReuseAddress` will not affect the binding. It only affects some specifics of what connections get refused or accepted.

As a side note - what's the point of waiting three hundred million years?

Comment: There is no difference between specifying 0.0.0.0 and null. Both mean INADDR_ANY. For that reason I'm surprised the more specific binds work afterwards. If there was no 0.0.0.0 I would expect the others to work, but not with 0.0.0.0 having already been bound.

Comment: @EJP I originally thought the same but I couldn't find a support for that idea in the documentation. I did find the statement that port 0 means _any_ at the same place, too.